# If Statement Always True (String)

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I have here a rather simple rock, paper, scissors program where I am having some trouble with if statements. For some reason, when I enter rock, paper, or scissors (True Values), the program always performs

```
if 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors' not in player:
   print("That is not how you play rock, paper, scissors!")
```

for some reason. The complete program is as below.

````
computer = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

com_num = randint(0,2)

com_sel = computer[com_num]

player = input('Rock, paper, scissors GO! ')
player = player.lower()

if 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors' not in player:
    print("That is not how you play rock, paper, scissors!")

if player == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors':    
    #win
    if player == 'rock' and com_sel == 'scissors':
        print('You win! ', player.title(), ' beats ', com_sel, '!', sep ='')
    if player == "paper" and com_sel == "rock":
        print('You win! ', player.title(), ' beats ', com_sel, '!', sep ='')
    if player == 'scissors' and com_sel == 'paper':
        print('You win! ', player.title(), ' beats ', com_sel, '!', sep ='')

    #draw
    if player == com_sel:
        print('It\'s a draw!')
        
    #lose
    if player == 'rock' and com_sel == 'paper':
        print('You lose.', com_sel.title(), "beats", player, '!', sep = '')
    if player == 'paper' and com_sel == 'scissors':
        print('You lose.', com_sel.title(), "beats", player, '!', sep = '')
    if player == 'scissors' and com_sel == 'rock':
        print('You lose.', com_sel.title(), "beats", player, '!', sep = '')```
````

Comment: Your conditions are wrong. What you want is something like `if player not in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:`

Comment: Why do you use `in` operator in your condition?

Comment: @Valeriy I initially used !=  but it didn't work so I thought I'd change it to not in instead which also doesn't work

Comment: @Vishnudev It works! I do want to ask, is this because the input entered into player is saved as an array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: @MinhoCho, see answers below. All behavior already explained there

Comment: Also would recommend using `random.choice` for computer's selection

Comment: @JenilDave Just changed it `randint` to `random.choice`. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions in `if` are wrong.

Consider the `if` statement with parentheses:

```
if ('rock') or ('paper') or ('scissors' not in player):
```

It will always return `True` because `rock` will always be true.

You need to swap conditions' operands

```
if player not in computer:
```

After this swap, this line becomes irrelevant (and also its conditions are wrong) You need to remove it:

```
if player == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors':
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this page with Python's operator precedences (the order in which they apply):

[https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html](https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Evalerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html)

You can see that `not in` is listed higher than `or` which means that it is evaluated first. Thus you can rewrite your if statement as:

```
if 'rock' or 'paper' or ('scissors' not in player): ...
```

Now we see that you really have an `or` of three things. The strings are not empty and thus the first `'rock'` already evaluates to true so the the whole thing is always true.

Answer (score 1):

To breakdown your statement,

```
if 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors' not in player:
```

Suppose, `player = 'scissors'`. This condition would be evaluated as,

(`'rock'`) or (`'paper'`) or (`'scissors' not in player`)

which again evaluates to,

`True or True or False`

Hence evaluating to `True` always because string(Eg 'rock') always evaluates to True and ignoring others because of the `OR`(Any one True to be True). So whatever you put in player doesn't matter.

CORRECT CONDITION

```
if player not in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:
```

This statement checks if `player` is not in the given list.

Answer (score 1):

```py
if player not in {'rock', 'paper', 'scissors'}:
    print("That is not how you play rock, paper, scissors!")
...
```