# Python Dictionary if clause

Tags: python, if-statement

as you can tell, I just recently started to learn python.

While practising, I stumbled upon an issue, for which I don´t have an answer to why this is the case.

My Code looks like this:

```
d = {"Groningen": "GRO", "Berlin": "BER", "Rotterdam": "RTD"}
if "Budapest" or "Saigon" in d:
    print("Budapest or Saigon are in the dictionary")
else: 
    print("Budapest or Saigon are not in the dictionary")
```

Python now prints the if clause, even though "Budapest" or "Saigon" are not in the dictionary.

The solution is probably super simple, but I just can't figure it out myself.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer help you figure it out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63987341/if-statement-always-true-string



If not, the comparison should be:

`if "Budapest" in d or "Saigon" in d:`

Comment: `if "Budapest" or "Saigon" in d:` is same as `if True or ("Saigon" in d):`

Comment: Since dictionary keys are set-like objects, you can do set intersection `if {'Budapest', 'Saigon'} & d.keys():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect here, in fact the condition will *always* be true (because "Budapest" is truthy):

```
if "Budapest" or "Saigon" in d:
```

The correct way to write what you mean is:

```
if "Budapest" in d or "Saigon" in d:
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the condition given by you is not correct, try it in this way instead

```
d = {"Groningen": "GRO", "Berlin": "BER", "Rotterdam": "RTD"}
if "Budapest" in d or "Saigon" in d:
    print("Budapest or Saigon are in the dictionary")
else: 
    print("Budapest or Saigon are not in the dictionary")
```